# Can you use convention-based routing to declare routes that take multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

What I mean by that is I have several routes that take multiple parameters:

```
api/sockId/sockColor
api/sockId/sockBrand
api/sockId/sockSize
```

Can I declare just one route for all of these? I'm imagining something like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "TwoArgumentGeneralRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}"
);
```

and of course that would need to match up with my action methods:

```
public Task PostSockColor(int sockId, int sockColor);
public Task PostSockBrand(int sockId, int sockBrand);
public Task PostSockSize(int sockId, int sockSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, although I think the parameter names need to match the route.
So you would have to make your route something like:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{sockId}/{variant}"
```

Then your methods are only different by the `{action}` (method name):

```
public Task PostSockColor(int sockId, int variant);
public Task PostSockBrand(int sockId, int variant);
public Task PostSockSize(int sockId, int variant);`
```